# Independent text blocks for each line

Tags: html, css

I've just started playing with html and css and basically I've been learning everything from all the posts here but right now I'm stuck with something I cant seem to figure out how to do through research and decided to post a question for help.

I'm customising a simple portfolio style theme on tumblr, my question is regarding the text caption on the right of the picture

http://www.alvaserigrafia.pt/post/34608701054

I can only get the 3 text lines to display on a single block and I want each one of the lines to have its own block with proportional width. Can this be done with just html and css?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is where Firebug (Firefox extension), or the developer tools of your favorite browser, will come in handy. If you inspect the text element in question, you'll see that they're each wrapped within `<p>` tags.

The `<p>` tag is a block level element, which means it will automatically take up the full width of its parent. It's also what's recommended for...well...paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 0):

Each line is wrapped in a `p` element. Block level elements usually fill the whole width of the parent container; that's why they are "block" elements.

To get something that shrinks with the content, wrap the text in a `span`:

```
<p><span>text</span></p>
```

The `span` will only be as large as the text inside.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Each one of the image posts will have a 3 line caption describing it, the first for job name, second for the process used, and the third the specifics of the shirt (its for a screenprinting website).

Comment: Black text on white background is very dull and I want to have each line of white text on a black box

Comment: The problem is I cant figure out how to make a independent box for each one, because its one text entry it generates one block behind it, wich becomes a large black square containing the 3 lines. I tought of setting a fixed height to it but in this case it only shows behind the first line, I cant make the block break at the end of the paragraphs and begin again on the next one.

Comment: Maybe you should draw an image that shows what you want to achieve.

Comment: Try to wrap each `p` in one `div`.